# How to force the android system to open only my app based on the registered intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

Issue:
I've been working on an app that listens to a certain kind of intents depending on a given link format. My intent filter works as expected, I'm just wondering whether it's possible to force the android system to bypass the kind of dialog below and open only my app.
[image: Intent Filter]

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just wondering whether it's possible to force the android system to bypass the kind of dialog below and open only my app.

Do you own the domain of the URI that is being invoked? If so, than yes, [with app links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations).

If not, then no.

Answer (score 0):

you force user to use a specific browser by this:

```
String packageName = "com.android.yourBrowser"; 
String className = "com.android.browser.YourBrowserActivity"; 
Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
internetIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
internetIntent.setClassName(packageName, className);
```

Comment: The intent is coming from a different app I have no control over